# Separate Class for multiple action listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I want to find the best practice to separate actionListener to an individual class. Throughout my research , the only things that i found is to create one actionlistener for one class.java which did not solve my issue.

For an example ,
 
**launch.java**

```
public class launch {
   public launchSystem(){
   ....
   JButton click1 = new JButton("Click 1");
   JButton click2 = new JButton("Click 2");

   //--- Add actionListener 
   // click1.addActionListener(new clickAction_b);
   frame.add(click1);
   frame.add(click2);
 }
}
```

**listenerClass.java**

```
public class listenerClas {
class clickAction_A implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("click a");
        }
    }

    class clickAction_B implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("click b");
        }
    }
}
```

In this case , i want to add  "clickAction_b to my cliaddActionListener" but unable to do so . I tried using extend and interface but all failed. Is it even possible to linked multiple actionlistener like calling a method from a different class?

Comment: I would recommend looking at [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: And [Java Naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/)